# Change routes realative in React Js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have these import:

```
import {Input, InputTxtCenter} from '../../../components/forms/input/input.js';
import {ButtonRed} from '../../../components/buttons/';
import {TxtCenter} from '../../../components/misc/texts/texts.js';
```

and I want to transform these routes into something similar to this

```
import {ButtonRed, ButtonWarning} from 'buttons';
import {TxtCenter} from 'misc/text';
import {TxtCenter} from 'forms/input';
```

that is, that the system knows that importing will always be from the "components" folder

Is it possible to do this?
Without having to create the component in node_modules?

Answer (score 1):

I think this less of a React question, and more of a module resolution/aliasing one.

I assume that you are using some tool like babel, in which you can try [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver).

The main idea is to define aliases in your `.babelrc` file so that you can avoid keeping track of relative directory structure when importing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `.env` file containing `NODE_PATH=src` if you're using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). 
I recommend you to start any project using CRA with possible `eject` option if you really require customization.